# How to live reload ionic windows/android/ios app in visual studio?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, uwp, visual-studio-cordova

I'm debugging windows app but live-reload doesn't work despite I have watch task in task runner. I do not use ionic serve because in this case, plugins do not work. How can I manage visual studio to run my app with livereload even if it is android or windows app?

Answer (score 0):

No I think that will not work. Because on your Android or Windows device you are running a compiled version of your app. Which means you can't just update some `.js` or `.html` file. You need to build a new bundle and and create a new `.apk` if you change something.

If you are developing a pure native app in e.g. AndroidStudio there is also no live-reload because the code needs to be compiled before running on a device. A cordova/ionic app is nothing more than a native app containing a webview where your bundled .js code runs.

Comment: I can make it work by setting start page URL, but it doesn't reload whole platforms dependencies